# python: получить полную информацию об исключении

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, try, exception-handler

есть такой код:

```
print(func(123))
```

при попытке выполнить получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(func(123))
          ^^^^
NameError: name 'func' is not defined
```

Если ловлю исключение:

```
try:
    print(func(123))
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)
```

то получаю лишь такую информацию:

```
name 'func' is not defined
```

А можно ли через исключения получить полную информацию, в том числе информацию о файле в котором возникло исключение и номер строки на которой произошло исключение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный модуль [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) позволяет получить такую информацию. Можно напечатать, можно получить в виде строк всё, что нужно.

Примеры там сильно отличаются для разных версий питона, поэтому код не даю.

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция `sys.exc_info`:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except:
...     print(sys.exc_info())
... 
(<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>, ZeroDivisionError('division by zero'), <traceback object at 0x...>)
>>>
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).